# jQuery custom widget: Returning different object for chaining?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, widget

I’m writing a custom jQuery widget for images.
In It’s „constructor“ (`_create`-method) the image gets wrapped into a div-box:

```
$.widget("custom.bazinga", {
    _create: function () {
        var container = $('<div/>');
        $(this.element).wrap(container);
    }
});
```

How can I return the `<div>` element instead of the image? (For chaining the functions like this: )

```
$('#foo')
    .bazinga()
    .height(200);
```

By now, the height is applied to the image, not to the div-box (which is this, what I actually want).

Here you have a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PGcXF/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI Internals prevent you from receiving anything different than the invoking object. That is due to the limitations you have when using the $.widget method, as it is just not possible to influence the dynamically created "bazinga" method's return value.

One possible solution would be to implement that behaviour into the jquery-ui widget core, which i would not recommend (loss of upgrade- possibility and probably not quite easy to do).

Maybe a better/easier solution is to chain a "parent()" call to access the newly generated jquery element:

```js
$('#foo')
    .bazinga()
    .parent()
    .height(200);
```

Additionally, try to move all widget- related functionality into the widget ...

```js
$.widget("custom.bazinga", {
    _create: function () {
        this.element.wrap($('<div/>'));
        this.container = this.element.parent();

        // Set height of parent object
        this.container.height(this.options.height);

    }
});

// Set default options
$.custom.bazinga.prototype.options.height = 100;
```

... and use options to configure the widget

```js
$('#foo').bazinga({
    height: 200
});
```

Comment: Sounds conclusive. I will choose then an entirely different approach, as I had a bit of a misunderstanding of how the widgets-factory actually works.

Comment: You might be better off writing a jquery plugin, as you'll have full control over what your jquery-method does, and returns.